# Next JS билд. Отключить статику

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, nextjs

После билда, создалась папка .next.
Запускаю приложение через команду npm run start.
Но новые данные, допустим после билда добавить в БД запись и обновить страницу - не появляются. Можно как-то билдить проект не со статикой?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, вопрос в том как делать динамические страницы?
Или вопрос в добавлении новых страниц/роутов где-то в админке, чтобы потом они были доступны?

Если вы не знаете как получить данные из базы данных, вот пример из моего проекта на Next.js 13.

```
import PageContent from './PageContent'
...
export default async function Page(pageParams) {

  let params = await getPageData(pageParams);

  return (
    <PageContent {...params} />
  );
}

export async function getPageData(pageParams) {
  let data = {};
  // здесь запрос к базе данных, или к любому другому асинхронному сервису
  return {
    pageData: JSON.stringify(data)
  }
}
```